# How does snmpd process SNMP requests?

Tags: net-snmp, snmpd

I am new to the SNMP protocol. I want to know how `snmpd` processes SNMP requests. For example:

```
snmpget -v1 -c public localhost sysName
```

My understanding is it is implementing MIBs, e.g. SNMPv2-MIB, but is executing the `uname -n` command?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question by hitting the edit link.

Comment: @ashutosh-kumar Does answer below help or do you need more info  ?

Answer (score 0):

For the net-snmp snmpd mapping for the sysname OID see [system_mib.c](https://github.com/winlibs/net-snmp/blob/master/agent/mibgroup/mibII/system_mib.c) where it is **sometimes** indeed based on `uname`, see code snippet below:

```
#ifdef HAVE_GETHOSTNAME
   gethostname(sysName, sizeof(sysName));
#else
#ifdef HAVE_UNAME
   strlcpy(sysName, utsName.nodename, sizeof(sysName));
#else
#if defined (HAVE_EXECV) && !defined (mingw32)
   sprintf(extmp.command, "%s -n", UNAMEPROG);
  /*
   * setup defaults
   */
   extmp.type = EXECPROC;
   extmp.next = NULL;
   exec_command(&extmp);
   strlcpy(sysName, extmp.output, sizeof(sysName));
   if (strlen(sysName) >= 1)
      sysName[strlen(sysName) - 1] = 0; /* chomp new line */
#else
   strcpy(sysName, "unknown");
#endif /* HAVE_EXECV */
#endif /* HAVE_UNAME */
#endif /* HAVE_GETHOSTNAME */
```

To understand how `snmpd` internally works look at [agent architecture](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Agent_Architecture) page on net-snmp site. 
It is detailed and also explains how to extend net-snmp with new MIBs.